# Uploading files to remote file server (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, server, upload

There seems to be similar questions to this on here, but I have not found my situation exactly so I thought I'd try and ask.

Currently I have a small file uploading website (files up to 2GB) which has the process;

1. Person visits and uploads file
2. Name of file gets generated
3. File gets uploaded directly to S3 using multi-chunk upload
4. File data gets put into the SQL database (link to file, name, size etc)
5. Returns link to file to download

I want to replace step 3 using my own remote storage server and just would like to know the quickest way to upload to a remote server through PHP. So far the only options I can see is to either use cURL to transfer the file once uploaded locally or to upload the file directly to the storage server.

Uploading to the storage server seemed like a good choice at first, but then updating the database on the main server seems difficult as all the processing will be on the remote server (unless there is an easier way?).

Uploading via cURL seems like it would be slow as it's initially uploaded to the local server and then moved.

Any advice would be great as I'm struggling to find a way to do this currently. For info, I'm using [simpleUpload.js](http://simpleupload.michaelcbrook.com/) to upload the file currently

Thank you!

Comment: What code have you already tried?

Comment: Tried a lot so far. I'd just like to move away from S3. I've tried cURL, but I would like a way to upload the temp file direct to the server (before saving locally) - but I cannot seem to get that working.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up finding this out by experimenting. On the server side it needed the below code to send the file;

```
// Grab the data to send
$data = array(
    'file' => new CurlFile($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $_FILES["file"]["type"],   $_FILES["file"]["name"]),
    'upload_folder' => 'foldername'
);

// Prepare the cURL call to upload the external script
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://external.com/upload.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

On the external server that it is sending to, you will need the below to grab it;

```
// Holder array
$output = array();

// Store the folder that is sent
$folderName = $_POST['upload_folder'] . '/';

// Attempt to create it
if(mkdir($folderName)) {
    // Move the file into the folder
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $folderName . $_FILES['file']['name'])) {
        $output['success'] = true;
        $output['message'] = 'upload_success';
    }else{
        // Upload failed
        $output['success'] = false;
        $output['message'] = 'upload_fail';
    }
}else{
    // Could not create dir
    $output['success'] = false;
    $output['message'] = 'dir_create_fail';
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone out.